# MySQL Join duplicate issue?

Tags: mysql

Consider the following MySQL tables:

*MORTALITY* (contains which raisers have deceased piglets)

```
raiserID  |  issuedDate  |  rotationNo |  numberDead
-----------------------------------------------------
   0052      2012-08-03         1             3
```

*PIGLET_PO* (contains the purchase of piglets transactions by raisers)

~ raisers can have multiple records here

```
raiserID  |  deliveredDate  |  rotationNo  |  noOfDeliveredPigs  |  sellerID
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   0052       2012-07-20          1                  10                1
   0052       2012-07-21          1                  15                1
```

*SELLER_LIST*

```
sellerID |  sellerName  
------------------------
    1       Solar Farm
```

Expected Result:

```
sellerName  |  population  |  deceased
-----------------------------------------
Solar Farm         25            3
```

- a Raiser is a person who takes care/raises pigs/hogs
- rotationNo is a unique identifier that refers to the raising cycle a raiser has undertaken or is currently undertaking

So far I have the following query that gives me a result similar to the expected one, the only catch is **I'm getting a value of 6 instead of a 3 for the deceased column**. I'm not sure but my guess is it has something to do with the piglet_po having two records/row. What am I missing here?

```
SELECT s.sellerName AS sellerName, SUM(p.noOfDeliveredPigs) AS population, SUM(numberDead) AS heads
FROM mortality m

JOIN piglet_po p
ON m.raiserid = p.raiserid
AND m.rotationNo = p.rotationNo

JOIN seller_list s
ON p.sellerID = s.sellerID

// This WHERE condition and the given string value that follow came from and is based on
a select drop-down box and shouldnt be modified since this is how I display them in html
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(m.issuedDate, '%M %Y') = 'August 2012' 
GROUP BY sellerName
HAVING SUM(numberDead) != 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have duplicate values for columns used in join for table `piglet_po(p.rotationNo)`. Instead try this or you can also use `DISTINCT` clause in `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT s.sellerName AS sellerName, SUM(p.noOfDeliveredPigs) AS population, 
       SUM(numberDead) AS heads
FROM mortality m
    JOIN (SELECT rotationNo, raiserid, sellerID, SUM(noOfDeliveredPigs) AS noOfDeliveredPigs
          FROM  piglet_po 
          GROUP BY rotationNo, raiserid, sellerID
         ) p
         ON m.raiserid = p.raiserid
            AND m.rotationNo = p.rotationNo
    JOIN seller_list s
         ON p.sellerID = s.sellerID
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(m.issuedDate, '%M %Y') = 'August 2012'
GROUP BY sellerName
HAVING SUM(numberDead) != 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I modified my query based on your answer, the deceased column is now 3 but the problem is the value for population became 10 whereas it should be 25 (sum of 10 and 15).

Comment: I just had to add sellerID in your nested SELECT since I am getting an unknown column error and I am now getting the desired result. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select sellername , population  , deceased 
from
    (select p.rotationno,p.raiserid,s.sellername as sellername
           , sum(p.noofdeliveredpigs) as population 
    from piglet_po p
    join seller_list s
    on p.sellerid = s.sellerid 
    group by p.rotationno,p.raiserid,sellername)p
join
    (select rotationno,raiserid,sum(numberdead) as deceased
    from mortality 
    where date_format(issueddate, '%m %y') = 'august 2012'
    group by rotationno,raiserid)m
on m.raiserid = p.raiserid
and m.rotationno = p.rotationno
```

Comment: I am getting "Unknown column 'm.issuedDate' in 'where clause'" error, I will recheck again but I dont think this is due to a typo on my part.

Comment: Thanks for the update, yours is now working as well, thank you!